# How to get the AWS Account Name using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I'm trying to get the **AWS Account Name** to be able to use it later in my Terraform Code. I only have Account access so I not am able to use resources that need Organization privileges.

I thought this would work:

```
data "aws_iam_account_alias" "current" {}

output "account_id" {
  value = data.aws_iam_account_alias.current.account_alias
}
```

But it returns an empty list as the Account has no Aliases (turns out **Account Name** is different from **Account Alias**).

Is there any similar way to get the **Account Name** using Terraform? (having full account permission but no organization permission)

Comment: Have you set the [account alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/accounts/latest/reference/manage-acct-alias.html) already?

Comment: no, as what I'm trying the get is the account_name and not the account_alias. If I use the CLI with:
```
aws iam list-account-aliases
```
I get and empty list. 
```
{
    "AccountAliases": []
}
```

Comment: What is Account name? Account number?

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

output "account_id" {
  value = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
}

output "caller_arn" {
  value = data.aws_caller_identity.current.arn
}

output "caller_user" {
  value = data.aws_caller_identity.current.user_id
}
```

Source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/caller_identity

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [aws_caller_identity](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/caller_identity) data source to get the ID or ARN from the current account.  It is analogous to the output of `aws sts get-caller-identity`.  If you really need the *Friendly Name* of the account and not simply the ID, you can try to get it via the [aws_organizations_organization data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/organizations_organization), which exports all available accounts, with their ARN, ID, Name, and a few other attributes.  Because you mentioned that you don't have organizations access, this might not be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

AWS is horrible in naming, and AWS IAM account seems to be something different from AWS organization.

I believe what you are looking for is an AWS organization name, as I was looking for a name as well, but only got empty aliases, although I could be wrong.

You can get it [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_organization#attributes-reference) in Terraform.

Or from the CLI with:

```
aws aws organizations describe-account --account-id XXXXX
```

**Edit:** Link to the SO question which answered my question: [The differences between IAM and AWS Organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525514/the-differences-between-iam-and-aws-organization)